# How to execute commands with Android SDK like a terminal?

Tags: c#, java, android, sdk, command

I want to develop a terminal app in Android.

In C#, we have:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path of aplication")
```

Its like running a program directly because each command is a program in Windows. I don't know how it works in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find other solution, thank for all guys

http://saurabh-nigam.blogspot.com/2010/10/running-android-native-code.html

this project make the same: https://github.com/gimite/android-native-exe-demo

Answer (score 3):

Use [ProcessBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to create OS processes.

Comment: +1: It's particularly good on POSIX platforms (i.e., Linux, OSX and all other Unix-based systems) because you can avoid having to reparse the command invocation by specifying the arguments as a list, _and_ the max length of arguments is much longer.

Comment: I cant find the way to do this in my android with this solution and i rooted my android to try that solution but dont works, thank for all. :)